# Expresso-store: How do I show a button if the cart has items in?

Tags: expresso-store

I'm using this to check if there is anything in the cart, but it throws an error on the front end. Is there a different ay to do this?

{exp:store:cart}
{if items}Go to Order Form{/if}
{/exp:store:cart}

The error:
Message: Array to string conversion
Filename: libraries/Functions.php
Line Number: 2584

Answer (score 1):

Just needed to use {items}{/items}.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `{no_items}` to check if the cart is empty:

```
{exp:store:cart}

    {if no_items}
        Your cart is empty!
    {/if}

    Your cart: {order_qty} items - {order_total}

{/exp:store:cart}
```

Comment: Thanks Ian, any idea how to show if a cart is not empty?

Comment: Yep, you just place everything outside the `{if no_items}` tag pair as normal. So the `{exp:store:cart}` tag pair *is* your not empty condition in the example above.